# Framework 4.5 to 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've developed a website on ASP.NET and C#. The project is done. 
Unfortunately, I didn't notice that the Framework was targeted to 4.5.
I've installed Windows 7  on my computer.

How can I change the framework 4.5 to 4.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click your project and select it's properties. In the "Application" panel, you will have a combobox that allows you to change the target .NET Framework. However, know that you may break your solution if you use some features unique to 4.5, so you might have to rewrite some stuff... or not.

You can "downgrade" your target Framework to any version you like up to .NET 2.0.